# parsing using split_to_multimap without throwing an exception

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I want to parse out the values which are assigned to the variables without throwing exception:

e.g I want this to return 3 (which it does)

```
select try_cast(array_join(element_at(split_to_multimap('a=3,b=5', ',', '='), 'a'), '') as int)  as a
```

I want this to return NULL (unfortunately it throws an exception)

```
select try_cast(array_join(element_at(split_to_multimap('a=3Xb=5', ',', '='), 'a'), '') as int)  as a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html?highlight=try#id4):

> Evaluate an expression and handle certain types of errors by returning NULL.

```sql
select try(
    cast(
        array_join(
            element_at(
                split_to_multimap('a=3Xb=5', ',', '='), 'a'), '') as int)) as a
```